# PHP: echo as condition of if statament?

Tags: javascript, php, function, if-statement, echo

I need to put echo as condition of if statement. So, for example:

```
<html>

...
...

<body>

  <form onsubmit"<?php $c=false; if(echo "<script>example();</script>";){ $c=true; } echo "\""; if($c){ echo "action=\"./\"";} method="post">
    ...
 </form>

...
...

<script>
 function example()
 {
   alert("This is only an example");
   if(..) return true;
   return false;
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I need to create a function in JavaScript (this top is **only** an example, but, in realty, it is more complicated) and call it in the if statement.

**Update**
The code should be execute "action" of the form only if the Javascript function is true.

Comment: You want to call JS at server-side? Not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429

Comment: Be more specific about what should happen when. Right now, your example is not making much sense.

Comment: Sorry, whats mean it?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. what do you mean with "echo as condition in if statement"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP runs in the server. JavaScript runs in the client. So php can't use a js variable or its function to server side action. What u can do is , u can call JS function from PHP like

```
echo "<script> myFunction() </script>";
```

But in the same same case, u can use php values for JS actions,
eg

```
<script>
var x = <?php echo $myVar ?>
if(x == true){ 
   alert("yahooo"); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, this won't "call" the js-function. It will just print that string out, send it to the client that will parse it and execute the function. It's a big big difference.

Comment: @Sav - Like multiple people already told you, _you can **not** call javascript functions from PHP_. PHP is executed on the server, returning the result to the browser that will execute any javascript.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Yea that will call the function, but no use.. It will jus print only ..(as of my knowledge)

Comment: No, the javascript engine in the browser will _call_ the function. This will just print the string. Call and print are two totally different things.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understand... and for this I asked this question... I need to check if the JS function is "true" or "false" from PHP. Is it possible?

Comment: @Sav - Again, no! When your javascript is executed on the _client_, all PHP code has already been executed on the _server_. These are two totally different environments.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Perfect, but Is there a method that do that I would do?


**Update**
So, I could put PHP code (includes the form...) in JS code?